# JavaScript for nested loop - want to know step by step of calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner.
Can anyone let me know the step by step (each step / condition) of a "nested for loop" in the below code written for finding Prime Numbers between two numbers.

```js
const number1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter the lower number"));
const number2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter the higher number"));

console.log(`The prime numbers between ${number1} and ${number2} are: `);

for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
  let flag = 0;
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i > 1 && flag == 0) console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You want someone to explain every line of code to you?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to understand an algorithm if you're a beginner is to take a concrete example, and do manually on a paper what happens by following the code. We can say 3 and 5 are the numbers:

`-> low: 3, high: 5`

We will enter the first for, which will initialize `i` with `3`

- 1st for: `i = 3`

  - we declare a `flag` with the value `0` (if it ever becomes `1`, the number is not prime).
  - we enter the second for, which checks from 2 to `i` (which at this point is `3`)

    - 2nd for: `j = 2`

      - we check if the rest of the division between `i` and `j` is `0` (`3 % 2`)
      - `3 % 2` is `1`, which is not `0`, so we will move on to the next iteration
    - 2nd for: `j = 3`, finishes because condition of `i < j` is not respected (`3 < 3` `false`)
  - now we check if `i` is greater than `1` ( `3 > 1` `true` ) and if `flag` is `0` (which it is, so we log `3` to the console)
  - `console.log(3)` will output `3`
- 1st for: `i = 4`

  - we declare a flag with the value `0` (if it ever becomes `1`, the number is not prime).
  - we enter the second for, which checks from `2` to `i` (which at this point is `4`)

    - 2nd for: `j = 2`

      - we check if the rest of the division between `i` and `j` is `0` (`4 % 2`)
      - `4 % 2` is `0`, so `flag` will become `1` and we break out of the second for.
    - now we check if `i` is greater than `1` ( `4 > 1` ) and if `flag` is `0` (which is not, so we do not show the number)
- 1st for: `i = 5`

  - we declare a `flag` with the value `0` (if it ever becomes `1`, the number is not prime).
  - we enter the second for, which checks from 2 to `i` (which at this point is `5`)

    - 2nd for: `j = 2`

      - we check if the rest of the division between `i` and `j` is `0` (`5 % 2`)
      - `5 % 2` is `1`, which is not `0`, so we will move on to the next iteration
    - 2nd for: `j = 3`

      - we check if the rest of the division between `i` and `j` is `0` (`5 % 3`)
      - `5 % 3` is `2`, which is not `0`, so we will move on to the next iteration
    - 2nd for: `j = 4`

      - we check if the rest of the division between `i` and `j` is `0` (`5 % 4`)
      - `5 % 4` is `1`, which is not `0`, so we will move on to the next iteration
    - 2nd for: `j = 5`, finishes because condition of `i < j` is not respected (`5 < 5` `false`).
  - now we check if `i` is greater than `1` ( `5 > 1` `true` ) and if `flag` is `0` (which it is, so we log `5` to the console)
  - `console.log(5)` will output `5`

The final result of the program will be logging `3` and `5` to the console as prime numbers.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first the definition of a prime number we are using: A prime number `n` is a number such that the numbers `2` to `n - 1` are not factors of `n`. This means that when we divide `n` by any number between `2` and `n - 1`, the remainder will NOT be 0.

So first, we create a for loop from `number1` to `number2`. We will check if each number in this range is a prime:

```
for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
```

Now, we actually have to check if the number, `i`, is a prime, using our method of checking to see if numbers from `2` to `i - 1` are NOT factors of `i`. We can use another for loop for this, with a variable `j` that goes from `2` to `i - 1`:

```
for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
  let flag = 0;
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

Inside our `j` loop, we check if `j` is a factor of `i`. Remember, if the number is prime, no `j` will be a factor of `i`, so the remainder of `i` divided by `j` will not be 0. If `i % j` is `0`, then we know `i` is not prime, so we exit out of the for loop and change `flag` to `1`, so we know not to output it:

```
for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
  let flag = 0;
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
```

If the for loop completed without `break`, which means that no `j` was a factor of `i`, we know that `i` is prime, which means `flag` is still `0`. This means if `flag` is `0`, we can print out `i`, since we know it is prime:

```
for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
  let flag = 0;
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i > 1 && flag == 0) console.log(i);
}
```

Then, `i` iterates to the next number and the cycle continues until the loop and code is finished.

Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification! :)

Comment: _"If the number is in fact a prime, we will change the variable flag from 0 to 1 so we know to not print i after the j loop ends."_ - this is almost the complete *opposite* of what the code does

Comment: Not a prime* sorry lol

Answer (score -2):

I Improved the code just for fun. As for the answer to your question, it's easily running from number1 to number2 -  foreach of those tries to divide it by all numbers lower than it. if none found (and it's not 1) then it is a prime number.

```js
const number1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter the lower number"), 10);
const number2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter the higher number"), 10);

console.log(`The prime numbers between ${number1} and ${number2} are: `);

for (let i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
  let flag = 0;
  for (let j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i > 1 && flag == 0) console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: O(n) to O(sqrtn) :)

Comment: nice improvement, but doesn't really answer the question and you provided no explanation on what's improved (for a beginner it might not make sense that Math.sqrt).

Comment: I like it. My explanation was a one liner. Might be a little cryptic for a beginner but once you understand it you know you understand. I wonder what the OP has to say.